# Optional parameters in SignalR 1.x Hub Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

i recently installed `SiganlR 1.x` in .net 4.0 `MVC4` application
and sample methods works fine when i use as it is

but i want to pass an optional parameter to hub method which can be `null` or `undefined` or `empty`

so added new parameter `toUser` to the hub method

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public void NewContosoChatMessage(string name, string message, string toUser = null)
    {
        Clients.All.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}

//javascript
contosoChatHubProxy.server.newContosoChatMessage(name, messsage);
//or
contosoChatHubProxy.server.newContosoChatMessage(name, messsage, '');
```

when the above script invoked, im getting Error at client side

```
Argument cannot be null or empty
Parameter name: toUser
```

need some expertise. 
Thank you.

Comment: when you call `contosoChatHubProxy.server.newContosoChatMessage(name, messsage)` your debugger goes there or not

Comment: no, its not hitting method break point. im getting error at client side from `connection.error` method

Comment: when i pass `(name, messsage, '')` is is working for me

Comment: Instead of using null have you tried string toUser = ""?  Then in your code just add validation looking for if(!String.IsNullorWhiteSpace(toUser))

Comment: @MarkTomlinson Yes, i tried `toUser = ""` but got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is little problem with signalR, and you can try after rebuild the application they are working on it 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/324
but
using `''` and `NULL` it is working for me[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, i tried by not passing optional parameter and wow it worked as well.. Thanks

Comment: @JAG thanks yes sometime problem comes because `cache` is not cleared